# Building Docker images on GCP's Cloud Build pulling artefacts from bucket

Tags: docker, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm building a Machine Learning pipeline and need to take several models, build a Docker image which includes them and then deploy this image to a machine on the clients premises.

The assumption is that baking the model files into the Docker image will make it easy to deploy?

Trouble is how to do this?

1 - Do I download, unzip and copy the models in the Dockerfile. How do I handle GCP credentials then?

2 - Do I somehow use GCP's Cloud Build to handle the download and then just COPY in the Dockerfile? Problem: there are noo examples for this in *any* CI/CD tool including Cloud Build.

I haven't even thought about versioning models in the bucket yet which would imply some sort of logic to select the model to download.

Are one of these options possible with Cloud Build?

Is option 1 more feasible than option 2?

Answer (score 1):

By your description, I can think of you pushing constantly ML models (files) to your repo that you want to give to your customers.

You can [Run Builds with Github checks and Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-with-github-checks) or [Run builds on Github](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-on-github) (which are pretty similar; the difference is the use of tools). Both options use [Build Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds).

Use any of these options to re-build your images on any changes to the source repository, or only changes that match certain criteria. With this, we can cover the how to do it and the possible issues with versioning.

While setting your Github repo for this, you will only be asked to identify yourself. Once they both are linked, credentials won't be an issue.

I can also think that you'll be updating the code that calls your ML models. If you consider having your code running on Cloud Run (for testing before sending it to your customers for instance), you can try the [Continuous Deployment from git on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build), which also uses Cloud Build triggers.

You can combine the info above with the [Quickstart for Docker and Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker).

Here is more info about [How using GitHub and Google Cloud Build simplify your CI process](https://github.blog/2018-07-26-simplify-your-ci-process/).

Said this, I think your option 2 is a better idea.

Comment: I guess thats the major difference between regular code products and ML products: the code doesn't change much with ML but the data that it trains on does, hence triggering on code change is not relevant.